# How do I initialize an array with the address of another array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I have class `Class1` with an array declared `array1`, so in `class1.h`, I have something like

```
Class Class1{
public:
    int array1[2];
}
```

and then later, in a different class's `.cpp` file, I have

```
Class1* class = new Class1();
int array0[2];
array0 = class->array1;
```

However, this gives me the error

`invalid array assignment`

How can I set the addresses of the arrays equal to each other so I can modify it remotely?

Comment: This doesn't look like a real code to me. Is it?

Comment: Yeah, it was a simple question, so I just wrote it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? *dangling pointers*

Comment: Originally it was all a part of the same class, but I'm refactoring it into different classes, so I need to send the array around.

Answer (score 4):

You can't refer to an array with another array. You have to either bind a *reference to an array* of the same type, or use a array-like type such as `std::array<int, 2>`.

Array reference:

```
Class1 a;
int (&array0)[2] = a.array1;  // array0 is a reference to a.array1
```

`std::array` reference:

```
#include <array>

class Class1{
public:
    std::array<int, 2> array1;
};
```

then

```
Class1 a;
std::array<int, 2>& array0 = a.array1; // array0 is a reference to a.array1
```

Both these approaches ensure that the full type information of the array is available via the reference. This means, for example, that you can use the references with `std::begin` and `std::end` or in a range-based for-loop.

Note that `class` is a keyword. You should not use it for naming variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need access to *the same* array, you could use a pointer:

```
Class1* class = new Class1();
int *array0 = class->array1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't a reference would be a more suitable solution?

Comment: As far as I know he seems to want access to the whole array, not just to the first element. Maybe the PO could clarify?

Comment: I meant a reference to the array, not just to an int

Comment: I agree with @Roddy. With a plain pointer, you need to keep track of the size of the array separately. Given the limited information provided the question, it seems a reference is a better option, being both safer and easier to use.

Comment: This works, I suppose as I'm not changing the size of the array. However, if that is the case, I think how to reference the array would be useful. As far as the question is concerned, this is an appropriate solution.

Comment: If you want to do things better and safer, I'd use stl arrays, as suggested elsewhere, but that would require modifying your class definition too.